# UIButton Background Image is outside the button

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

[image: dotted box is where image appears, I want it within the limits of the button]

I'm putting the finishing touches to my first iOS app before I try to get it approved by Apple. One of the last things I've done is put images on two buttons. However, now I've added these buttons they don't appear where I want them to.

Is there any way to edit the dotted box in Xcode 5? I can't drag it around with my mouse and I think that's defining where the image shows up. I'd line the dotted box to be inside the solid box.

There is a slight misalignment in the other button that's shown in the picture, but that's not quite as bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured it out, set the constraints `Leading Space` and `Trailing Space` to `Automatic`, this shows up as SuperView in the Xcode UI.

[image: Solution]

Click on the gear cog and then select edit and click the tick-box next to Automatic and it should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

The dotted frame is the location of where the button is supposed to be based on the layout constraints, but those constraints are conflicting with the frame you have currently set. Select that button, go to editor, go to resolve auto layout issues, and select update frames. (Or use the shortcut on the storyboard bar at the bottom right of storyboard.)

Answer (score 0):

There are two mistakes:

- The Button is not where it is supposed to be, according to its constraints. It will be in a different place at runtime. The orange dashed frame indicates that
- The button is not placed so that its position is not ambiguous. Judging from your screenshot, there is a height constraint missing. That is indicated by the red dashed frame

Think about your button: You have told where the horizontal center should be, where the right edge should be, its width, and thus the left edge, but no constraint is telling your button its height!

The easyest way: click [image: resolve layout issues button]

at the bottom of your editor. That allows you to automatically

- adust your constraints, if the button is where you want it to be
- add the missing constraints, to have an unambiguous layout

---edit---

From your first screenshot, it seems like you did not even align the vertical position, but only those two elements´ horizontal centers to be at equal height. In this case, you need either a bottom or top vertical space constraint.